# How can I sort a multivalued string field with docValues in Apache Solr 6?

Tags: string, sorting, solr, field, multivalue

We are trying to sort on a multivalued field which is defined like this:

```
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="fieldName" type="StrField"/>
```

The Solr we use is: 6.0.1.1.2338

When trying to sort on the field "fieldName", we get the following error:

```
"msg": "can not sort on multivalued field: fieldName",
```

Then we tried to use field functions to enable the sorting:

```
&sort=field(fieldName,min)+asc
```

Or like:
    &fl=fieldName_alias:field(fieldName,min)&sort=fieldName_alias+asc

Then we are getting the following error:

```
"Selecting a single value from a multivalued field is not supported for this field: fieldName(type: StrField)"
```

Doing more research, we realised that the field-Function can only work for numeric types. Now we are not sure, how to implement the sorting. I hope it is possible to do without reindexing.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How you want to sort on multivalued string? Which string to choose?

Comment: The first or last element in the field would be fine for me. Alternatively, we could order them alphabetically in the field and use again either first or last entry.

Comment: Try to see if `def` shortcuts the multivalued lookup in some way. The correct way to implement this would be to index your decided sort value/key to a different, single valued field. There are update request processors for handling that exact use case available.